# Tracing the path of non-na cells in a raster

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster (see the plot below) that was created by masking from a bigger raster using a line shapefile. The final aim is to remove spikes and valleys and smooth the raster values along the line. But the problem is I can't figure out how to first sort the values based on the order of occurrence when tracing the path from one end to another. As you can see I can't sort by lat or long as the path doesn't follow a single direction. Obviously, I can't sort by using the cell values (as there are spikes and valleys along the way).

Is there any algorithm/method to number raster cells based on the order of occurrence along a path?

I am mainly using R, so any suggestion using R functions would be great.

Note: I asked a similar question in StackOverflow, but no answers yet. I feel this question is more relevant to this site, so posting a slightly modified version of the question.

[image]

Data (in R format)

```
raster::rasterFromXYZ(a) where a is 

structure(list(x = c(332568.9801, 332568.9801, 332578.9801, 332578.9801, 
332588.9801, 332588.9801, 332588.9801, 332598.9801, 332598.9801, 
332598.9801, 332608.9801, 332608.9801, 332608.9801, 332618.9801, 
332618.9801, 332618.9801, 332628.9801, 332628.9801, 332638.9801, 
332638.9801, 332638.9801, 332648.9801, 332648.9801, 332658.9801, 
332658.9801, 332668.9801, 332668.9801, 332678.9801, 332678.9801, 
332688.9801, 332688.9801, 332688.9801, 332688.9801, 332688.9801, 
332688.9801, 332998.9801, 333008.9801, 333018.9801, 333028.9801, 
333038.9801, 333048.9801, 332688.9801, 332698.9801, 332958.9801, 
332968.9801, 332978.9801, 332988.9801, 332998.9801, 333048.9801, 
333058.9801, 333068.9801, 332698.9801, 332708.9801, 332718.9801, 
332748.9801, 332758.9801, 332768.9801, 332778.9801, 332788.9801, 
332798.9801, 332808.9801, 332818.9801, 332828.9801, 332838.9801, 
332848.9801, 332858.9801, 332868.9801, 332878.9801, 332888.9801, 
332898.9801, 332908.9801, 332918.9801, 332928.9801, 332938.9801, 
332948.9801, 332958.9801, 333068.9801, 332718.9801, 332728.9801, 
332738.9801, 332748.9801, 333068.9801, 333068.9801, 333068.9801, 
333068.9801, 333068.9801, 333068.9801, 333078.9801, 333078.9801, 
333078.9801, 333078.9801, 333078.9801, 333078.9801, 333078.9801, 
333088.9801, 333088.9801, 333088.9801, 333088.9801, 333088.9801, 
333088.9801, 333088.9801, 333078.9801, 333088.9801, 333078.9801, 
333078.9801, 333078.9801, 333078.9801, 333078.9801, 333068.9801, 
333078.9801, 333068.9801, 333068.9801, 333068.9801, 333058.9801, 
333068.9801, 333058.9801, 333058.9801, 333068.9801, 333068.9801, 
333068.9801, 333068.9801, 333078.9801, 333078.9801, 333088.9801, 
333088.9801, 333098.9801, 333108.9801, 333108.9801, 333118.9801, 
333118.9801, 333128.9801, 333138.9801, 333138.9801, 333148.9801, 
333158.9801, 333158.9801, 333168.9801, 333178.9801, 333188.9801, 
333198.9801, 333198.9801, 333208.9801, 333218.9801, 333228.9801, 
333228.9801, 333238.9801, 333248.9801, 333258.9801, 333258.9801, 
333258.9801, 333268.9801, 333268.9801, 333278.9801, 333278.9801, 
333278.9801, 333288.9801, 333288.9801, 333298.9801, 333298.9801, 
333308.9801, 333308.9801, 333318.9801, 333318.9801, 333328.9801, 
333328.9801, 333338.9801, 333338.9801, 333338.9801, 333348.9801, 
333348.9801, 333358.9801), y = c(3061197.4038, 3061187.4038, 
3061187.4038, 3061177.4038, 3061177.4038, 3061167.4038, 3061157.4038, 
3061157.4038, 3061147.4038, 3061137.4038, 3061137.4038, 3061127.4038, 
3061117.4038, 3061117.4038, 3061107.4038, 3061097.4038, 3061097.4038, 
3061087.4038, 3061087.4038, 3061077.4038, 3061067.4038, 3061067.4038, 
3061057.4038, 3061057.4038, 3061047.4038, 3061047.4038, 3061037.4038, 
3061037.4038, 3061027.4038, 3061027.4038, 3061017.4038, 3061007.4038, 
3060997.4038, 3060987.4038, 3060977.4038, 3060977.4038, 3060977.4038, 
3060977.4038, 3060977.4038, 3060977.4038, 3060977.4038, 3060967.4038, 
3060967.4038, 3060967.4038, 3060967.4038, 3060967.4038, 3060967.4038, 
3060967.4038, 3060967.4038, 3060967.4038, 3060967.4038, 3060957.4038, 
3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 
3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 
3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 
3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 
3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 3060957.4038, 
3060947.4038, 3060947.4038, 3060947.4038, 3060947.4038, 3060947.4038, 
3060937.4038, 3060927.4038, 3060917.4038, 3060907.4038, 3060897.4038, 
3060897.4038, 3060887.4038, 3060877.4038, 3060867.4038, 3060857.4038, 
3060847.4038, 3060837.4038, 3060837.4038, 3060827.4038, 3060817.4038, 
3060807.4038, 3060797.4038, 3060787.4038, 3060777.4038, 3060767.4038, 
3060767.4038, 3060757.4038, 3060747.4038, 3060737.4038, 3060727.4038, 
3060717.4038, 3060707.4038, 3060707.4038, 3060697.4038, 3060687.4038, 
3060677.4038, 3060667.4038, 3060667.4038, 3060657.4038, 3060647.4038, 
3060647.4038, 3060637.4038, 3060627.4038, 3060617.4038, 3060617.4038, 
3060607.4038, 3060607.4038, 3060597.4038, 3060597.4038, 3060597.4038, 
3060587.4038, 3060587.4038, 3060577.4038, 3060577.4038, 3060577.4038, 
3060567.4038, 3060567.4038, 3060567.4038, 3060557.4038, 3060557.4038, 
3060557.4038, 3060557.4038, 3060557.4038, 3060547.4038, 3060547.4038, 
3060547.4038, 3060547.4038, 3060537.4038, 3060537.4038, 3060537.4038, 
3060537.4038, 3060527.4038, 3060517.4038, 3060517.4038, 3060507.4038, 
3060507.4038, 3060497.4038, 3060487.4038, 3060487.4038, 3060477.4038, 
3060477.4038, 3060467.4038, 3060467.4038, 3060457.4038, 3060457.4038, 
3060447.4038, 3060447.4038, 3060437.4038, 3060437.4038, 3060427.4038, 
3060417.4038, 3060417.4038, 3060407.4038, 3060407.4038), ele = c(1201.09436035156, 
1201.66271972656, 1201.96130371094, 1201.96130371094, 1201.96130371094, 
1201.96130371094, 1202.08666992188, 1202.18505859375, 1202.23205566406, 
1202.23205566406, 1202.23205566406, 1202.12902832031, 1202.23205566406, 
1202.23205566406, 1202.130859375, 1202.23205566406, 1202.31982421875, 
1202.41235351562, 1202.41235351562, 1202.66650390625, 1203.02331542969, 
1203.02331542969, 1203.02331542969, 1203.02331542969, 1203.02331542969, 
1203.02331542969, 1203.02331542969, 1203.02331542969, 1203.12805175781, 
1203.12805175781, 1203.27319335938, 1203.27319335938, 1203.27319335938, 
1203.357421875, 1203.71594238281, 1204.94604492188, 1204.94604492188, 
1204.94604492188, 1204.94604492188, 1204.94604492188, 1205.32995605469, 
1203.63305664062, 1203.71594238281, 1205.53466796875, 1205.68115234375, 
1204.92346191406, 1204.94604492188, 1204.94604492188, 1205.32995605469, 
1205.35986328125, 1205.35888671875, 1203.73864746094, 1203.63488769531, 
1203.73864746094, 1203.73864746094, 1204.12939453125, 1204.55810546875, 
1204.55810546875, 1205.43127441406, 1204.63513183594, 1203.80871582031, 
1203.80871582031, 1203.80871582031, 1203.80871582031, 1203.80871582031, 
1203.80871582031, 1204.05310058594, 1204.24133300781, 1204.24133300781, 
1204.24133300781, 1204.24133300781, 1204.412109375, 1205.53466796875, 
1205.46630859375, 1205.53466796875, 1205.53466796875, 1205.36047363281, 
1203.73864746094, 1203.73864746094, 1203.73864746094, 1203.73864746094, 
1205.35888671875, 1205.35888671875, 1205.35888671875, 1205.54125976562, 
1206.54333496094, 1206.54333496094, 1206.54333496094, 1206.78332519531, 
1206.56323242188, 1206.41760253906, 1206.41760253906, 1206.39172363281, 
1206.15344238281, 1206.15344238281, 1206.10241699219, 1206.10400390625, 
1206.10241699219, 1206.10241699219, 1206.10241699219, 1206.10241699219, 
1206.43054199219, 1206.43054199219, 1206.87121582031, 1207.04479980469, 
1207.04479980469, 1207.34387207031, 1207.35961914062, 1207.35961914062, 
1207.35961914062, 1207.35961914062, 1207.28234863281, 1207.41857910156, 
1207.58874511719, 1207.58874511719, 1207.58874511719, 1207.58874511719, 
1207.58874511719, 1207.58874511719, 1207.79296875, 1207.8388671875, 
1207.8388671875, 1207.8388671875, 1207.94274902344, 1207.94274902344, 
1207.89782714844, 1207.94274902344, 1207.94274902344, 1208.01794433594, 
1208.43347167969, 1208.53259277344, 1208.56506347656, 1208.56506347656, 
1208.53442382812, 1208.56506347656, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53625488281, 
1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 
1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 
1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.720703125, 1209.52807617188, 
1209.81579589844, 1209.81579589844, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 
1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 
1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1210.79309082031, 
1210.46276855469, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 
1210.0283203125, 1210.03039550781, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 
1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-171L))
```

Comment: Have you tried `rasterToPolygons` and then skeletonisation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595117/identify-a-linear-feature-on-a-raster-map-and-return-a-linear-shape-object-using

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I am not sure skeletonisation will solve the issue. I know the coordinates and cell numbers of the raster cells. I just need to find a way to sort the cells based on the order of occurrence along the path (from one end to another).

Comment: It will give you the path, but yes there's other ways based on nearest neighbours. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the nearest-neighbour approach:

First, setup:

```
library(raster)
source("path.R") # creates "a"
r = rasterFromXYZ(a)
```

get x,y,V for the non-NA raster points:

```
pts = rasterToPoints(r)
```

this many of them

```
npts = nrow(pts)
```

get the nearest k=2 neighbours from the X and Y coords:

```
library(FNN)
nn2 = get.knn(pts[,1:2], k=2)
```

build a full edge matrix.

```
nni = nn2$nn.index
edges = rbind(
    cbind(1:npts,nni[,1]),
    cbind(1:npts,nni[,2])
)
```

Now connect the edges in a graph:

```
library(igraph)
g = graph_from_edgelist(edges)
```

Compute the distances of each node from the first node. This assumes the first node is a starting point.

```
dpath = distances(g, 1)[1,]
```

Plot the raster, then the points connected in order of the distance from the first node:

```
plot(r)
lines(pts[order(dpath),])
```

[image]

There's possibly some minor refinement needed at the start and end because those nodes only have one nearest neighbour that you are interested in, so there's maybe a bit more work needed if these points are not easily identifiable (in this example they are the first and last points in the raster so that's easy).

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying to understand every line. Meanwhile a quick question - If the `dpath` is the sorted cell numbers in sequential order why does it contain repeated cell numbers (and a 0) at both ends?